# Skip some folders in a directory C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program, that creates a backup of some files with typical documents extensions on the C: drive. But there is this directory called "C:\Config.Msi". There is always a access denied exception. So I want to skip this folder, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a list of everything you want to skip:

```
//note this should be in config, not hard coded
var skip = new[]{
  @"c:\config.mail",
  @"c:\recycler"
};
```

And as you're processing, ignore files in those directories/ignore those directories:

```
foreach(var file in Directory.GetXxx(...)){
    if(skip.Any(s => file.StartsWith(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        continue;

    //process your file/dir here
```

---

Alternatively you can catch the AccessDeniedException and ignore it, which saves you having to maintain a list